# A class with default language settings

Tags: languages, class-options

I want to write a class which loads babel and other language aware packages and pass to all of them the option `ngerman` as default. But if another language is used in the options of the `\documentclass` then this language should be used. The only way I found to get this behaviour is this code

```
\ProvidesClass{mytest}[2013/11/27]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\preto\@classoptionslist{ngerman,}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{babel}
\endinput
```

which then can be used like this and `\documentclass[english]{mytest}` works as expected.

```
\documentclass{mytest}
\begin{document}
\bibname
\end{document}
```

But the `\preto\@classoptionslist{ngerman,}` looks a bit like a hack. Is there really no other way to pass a default option in a `.cls` to all (or some) packages?

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman}{babel}`?

Comment: @egreg: No this doesn't work, then `\documentclass[english]{mytest}` doesn't gives english but german words as the document options are processed before the package options.

Comment: My opinion is that classes should be language agnostic and language support should be added on a per document basis.

Comment: @egreg: classes are not language agnostic: you get "table of contents" as default and english hyphenation. I need a class with german defaults.

Comment: If you define all the `\*name` macros and `\today` in your class file, ending with `\language\l@ngerman`, you will have ngerman defaults in exactly the same way that `article.cls` has usenglish defaults.

Comment: This doesn't look like a huge hack to me. I would expect to find all the class options in `\@classoptonlist` so it seems like you are adding the option to the correct place. I think it is rare enough that the kernel doesn't need a dedicated macro.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A possible trouble with your hack, coming more form `babel`, is if the passed class option is `english,ngerman`: in such a case, "Last declared language option is 'ngerman', but the last processed one was 'english'" as a `babel`'s warning says.

Comment: Obviously this is a stupid question, but why not `\PassOptionsToClass`? (Before processing options and loading the class.) That would still run afoul of the point @DenisBitouzé made, I think.

Comment: @cfr: How can I add `\PassOptionsToClass` *in* the class so that it is process *before loading* the class? Beside this such options are not passed to subsequent packages as you can try out:`\PassOptionsToClass{ngerman}{article}\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}\begin{document}blub\end{document}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought you could use `\PassOptionsToClass` in a custom class before loading a standard class to pass it options. However, maybe this is dependent on `xkeyval`.

Comment: Or you could insist users specify a language when calling your class. Then it will work. (I don't understand why things are set up this way: why does `babel` see the options passed to your class iff you do not pass it any default?)

Comment: @AboAmmar Please remember that minor edits are discouraged. Moreover, major edits are discouraged when they break the OP's code! I have restored the comma which is essential to this working.

Comment: Oops. I missed restoring the second one....

Comment: @cfr I think the second comma disappeared earlier, due to some edit from someone else.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, right. I did look to review all the changes which had been made in the last edit. But I failed to look further back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the question from the unanswered list I will answer it myself:

Imho there is currently no better solution than the one proposed in the question.

Answer (score 5):

(I know this question is old, and maybe you've found a solution, but it's still lingering on the unanswered list.)

> I want to write a class which loads `babel` and other language aware
>   packages and pass to all of them the option `ngerman` as default.

Your assumption here is that all language-aware packages use the same option list as `babel`, which is unfortunately not the case. It may be that you have a specific list of language-aware packages that your class will load, where you can verify whether this is true, but this doesn't take into account any additional packages the user might want to load after they've loaded your class that may also require language support.

The other problem is, what happens if the user wants to use XeLaTeX? In this case, they'll more likely want `polyglossia`, and here there's another problem. From the `polyglossia` manual:

> polyglossia no longer supports loading language definition files as
>   package options!

It also doesn't accept `ngerman` as a language name. It must instead be `german` with the option `spelling=new`.

So even if you do find an easy way to add `ngerman` to the class option list, given that it doesn't contain any other language names, you still won't achieve your desired effect if a user of your class wants `polyglossia` instead of `babel`.

What of other language-aware packages? I've come across at least one class where the language is set using a key=value option in the form `language=enGB`. Given the increasing number of packages with a key=value option list, there may well be some packages that require the language set in this way as well. (I can't recall any off the top of my head, but I did consider it for one of my packages with a key=value option list, although in the end I decided it wasn't a good idea.)

I think that most packages that provide multilingual support tend to check for `babel` or `polyglossia` so that they can integrate with their caption mechanism (especially given the complications it can cause if they don't in multilingual documents). However, for those that don't, there's no guarantee at all that they will recognise `ngerman` as an option.

Therefore, it seems that the only practical solution to your question is to just concentrate on getting `babel` or `polyglossia` to set German as the default language if no language has been supplied by the user in the document class, and then assume that any other packages the user wants to load that has multilingual support will have the sense to check for `babel` or `polyglossia` and pick up the language lists from them.

The simplest method that I can think of to do this is:

```
\ProvidesClass{mytest}

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{tracklang}
\RequirePackage{afterpackage}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
 \newcommand{\@mytest@add@dialect}[1]{%
   \AfterPackage{polyglossia}{\setotherlanguage{\TrackedLanguageFromDialect{#1}}}%
 }
\else
 \newcommand{\@mytest@add@dialect}[1]{%
   \PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{babel}%
 }
\fi

\AnyTrackedLanguages
{
  \ForEachTrackedDialect{\this@dialect}{%
    \expandafter\@mytest@add@dialect\expandafter{\this@dialect}}

}
{
  \ifxetex
    \AfterPackage{polyglossia}{\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}}
  \else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman}{babel}
  \fi
}

\ifxetex
 \RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\else
 \RequirePackage{babel}
\fi

\endinput
```

This way, `ngerman` is only automatically added if the user hasn't specified any language options in the document class, so it's not added if they don't want it.

Comment: As I wrote my (rather special) class already loads babel, so polyglossia is not an issue (and even with xelatex I would prefer babel if the needed language files are adapted to xelatex). My main problem was not the various possible option names, but how to put such an option at the very begin of the option list. And imho the answer is that there is currently no better solution than my code (which works exactly as I want it). Beside this there is imho a need for some language interface on the kernel level.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree that there is definitely a need for some language interface in the kernel. Perhaps you should just post your comment as an answer given that no one else can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple languages in a custom class, I declared each languages as an option as follows:

```latex
% Class declaration
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{liedjify}[2022/03/06 Class for high quality thesis at uds, Cameroon]

\DeclareOption{french}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}
}

\DeclareOption{english}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}
}

\DeclareOption{german}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}
}

%% Process given options
\ProcessOptions\relax

%% Load base
\LoadClass[a4paper]{extreport}

\RequirePackage{babel} % support multiple languages writing

%% Additional TeX/LaTeX code...

\endinput
```

The user can then pass the selected language to the `\documentclass`.

Here is a usefull example for german (`\documentclass[german]{liedjify}` ), french (`\documentclass[french]{liedjify}` ), and english (`\documentclass[english]{liedjify}` ) languages:

```latex
\documentclass[german]{liedjify}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
See the chaper name for your language.
\end{document}
```