# Passing language parameter to \RequirePackage through \documentclass

Tags: packages, class-options

I've written my own CV class and set it up so all packages are required in the `.cls` file and the `.tex` file only uses `\documentclass`. I would like to keep it this way but still be able to select language and use the `\RequirePackage[language]{babel}` call in the `.cls` file. Is there a way to do this something like

`.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final,language]{MyCV}
```

`.cls` file:

```
\RequirePackage[language]{babel}
```

or do I have to move that setting to the `.tex` file?

Comment: There might be a way to do it (I don't know personally), but IMO classes should be language-agnostic. I understand this is for personal use, but what if someone else uses it and wants to use a different package (_e.g._ `polyglossia`) for language-specific features? My thought would be to keep it in the `.tex` file, but you can do as you please, of course. :-)

Comment: You *can* do `\RequirePackage{babel}` and specify the language(s) in the `.tex` file. However, in that case you must *always* specify a language when calling the class.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147243/a-class-with-default-language-settings?rq=1. I think this question is a duplicate of that one but it is not an SE duplicate as that question has no answer.