# Set global option (and pass it to all packages) in a custom class file

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I had a `tex`-file that basically started as follows

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper, hyperref, amsmath, headinclude=true, ngerman, final
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphix}
```

I converted this into my own custom class file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{kitbook}[2015/04/23 KITbook]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=KIT,prefix=KIT@}
...
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax

\LoadClass[
  a4paper, hyperref, amsmath, headinclude=true, ngerman, final
]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{ntheorem}
\RequirePackage{graphix}
```

The `tex`-file is reduced to

```
\documentclass{kitbook}
```

But suddenly I get a LaTeX warning that the options `hyperref`, `amsmath`, `headinclude=true` are unused. Babel gives the error that no language is specified and the option `final` is indeed used by the `scrbook` class but not by the `graphix` package.

It seems that there is a difference in the semantic of `\documentclass` and `\LoadClass`. Options that are given to `\documentclass` are made global and implicitely passed to all packages. But options given to `\LoadClass` are only used by the class itsself. That is the reason why `babel` does not get `ngerman` and so on.

Is there any way to make options global in a custom class file?

Especially, I see one major problem. The option `headinclude=true` is not used by any package that is explicitely loaded. (I believe it is used by `typearea` that itsself is loaded by `scrbook`.) Of course, I could use `\PassOptionToPackage{headinclude=true}{typearea}` but the problem with this approach is that I need to find out which package uses which option for every option and package and then call `\PassOptionToPackage` explicitely. This approach is not very promising.

Comment: I think, it should be `\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}`?

Comment: No, it is not. `\LoadClass{scrbook}` loads the class with all options. Those options that are given as optional argument, i.e. `\LoadClass[foo]{scrbook}`, and those options given by `\PassOptionsToClass{bar}{scrbook}`. Contrary,  `\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}` loads the class ONLY with those options given explicitly as optional argument, i.e. `\LoadClassWithOptions[foo]{scrbook}`. All options from  `\PassOptionsToClass{...}{...}` are ignored. Particulary, `\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}` loads the class with no options at all. However, both commands pass the options to the class only!

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I was excited to find your question, but disappointed to see that there is no answer. I think this problem is doubly confusing because options passed to `\LoadClass` will generate an *Unused global option(s)* warning despite the fact that they are not actually being treated as global options!

Comment: @DaoWen See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147243/2388