# LoadClass introduces "unused global options"

Tags: documentclass-writing

Consider the following (well-behaving) latex code, where the `hidelinks` option works as expected:

```
\documentclass[american, hidelinks, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Foo}
    \section{SFoo}

  Some reference to \autoref{chap:bar}.

  \chapter{Bar}
    \label{chap:bar}
    \section{SBar}

\end{document}
```

Now if I separate the preamble into its own class, i.e.,

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{some}[2018/01/09 Some Class]

\LoadClass[american, hidelinks, 12pt]{report}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{bookmark}
```

And re-write the MWE from above to use this class:

```
\documentclass{the-class-from-above}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Foo}
    \section{SFoo}

  Later, in \autoref{chap:bar}.

  \chapter{Bar}
  \label{chap:bar}
    \section{SBar}

\end{document}
```

I get the "unused global options" warning for both `hidelinks` and `american` (but not `12pt`). Indeed, all links appear with a red box, as if `hidelinks` is not there.

Is there a generic guideline on how to correctly load class options that I am missing?

EDIT:

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240198/set-global-option-and-pass-it-to-all-packages-in-a-custom-class-file) question is highly related, but is itself unanswered.

Comment: It does not seem to be though. `\usepackage[hidelinks]{bookmark}` fails to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options to `\documentclass` are "global options" and passed to all packages, but in your revised version the global option list is empty.  you need to use `hidelinks` option and explicitly load `hyperref`, as  passing that option to `report` does nothing. Similarly the `american` option does nothing unless you load babel and pass `american` to that.

Comment: `bookmark` does not take a `hidelinks` option.

That's why I chose it over `hyperref`, to exclude this possibility.

Comment: @dow ah i was thinking it passed it on, so you'd need to load hyperref then (i'll update the answer) .  Alternatively of course it's possible to fake things and forcibly add the options on to the macro that latex uses to store the global options but that's not a documented interface and probably not recommended.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your answer though. If `\documentclass` passes the options to all packages, then why does the first example work, since it loads `bookmark` and not `hyperref`?

Comment: I found this very closely related question, if you would like to take a look:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240198/set-global-option-and-pass-it-to-all-packages-in-a-custom-class-file

As it seems, the whole issue boils down to my not understanding how to pass options via `\LoadClass` (or similar) and ensure that they are indeed made global---as with `\documentclass`.

Comment: @dow as i said there is no supported way to set the global options other than `\documentclass`  You would have to add them to `\@classoptionslist` "by hand"

Comment: @dow in your first version, bookmark loads hyperref and then hyperref sees the global option `hidelinks`